# MVC3 not executing JQuery on partial updates

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

The first time I run the following JQuery code, it works fine and the call works, but after completing a partial update initiated by an Ajax call, it stops working:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".thumb").click(function () {
            $("#full").attr("src", $(this).data('main'));
        });
    });
```

Interestingly, the following code that initiates the partial updates continues to work:

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="Get" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#product-details-page" href="/Catalog/ProductGroupGrid?categoryId=2&amp;selectedProductId=561"><img alt="Category" src="/images/catalog/thumb/test.jpg" /></a>
                                </span>
```

FYI, my JQuery script function is located in the container of the partial view.  What could be causing it to stop working after the partial update?  Should I move the JQuery function into my PartialView?

**EDIT:** Moving it to the PartialView works, but it doesn't follow best practices of having the script located at the bottom of the document. In addition, if there are any other JQuery scripts on the page, in the container pages, then their scripts breaks too.  Ideally, I don't want to explicitly reexecute all the scripts on the page.  It would defeat the purpose of a reusable partial view.

Answer (score 1):

You may face this issue , if you want to perform any action on updated View.

In JQuery, on Document load it will fire events on any DOM Elelments.Once a view or part of a view is updated,jquery events will not fire on those elements.

You need not move the javascript code to partial view. Instead verify no actions are invoked on updated dom elements.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say "verify no actions are invoked on updated elements."  What action?

Comment: I mean , if any javascript code accessing "Dom elements in the updated Html". Lets say. i have one <div id="a">..</div> on page load, then Javascript can perform action on this "Div".But if a javascript action adds a new div like <div id="a">...<div id="newDiv">...</div></div>, then javascript cannot invoke any action on "newDiv". [Click here](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_doesn.27t_an_event_work_on_a_new_element_I.27ve_created.3F) for more information

Comment: Well obviously, my div is updated after the ajax call. There's an image that's replaced, but I am not adding or removing any elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving the click binding into a seperate function, such as InitThumbClick(), reference this in the document ready function, and then call it again whenever the page or partial view is reloaded, then jquery will be able to bind the click action to any new elements you have loaded.

Comment: How can this be done from a partial view?  Are you taking about on success event of the passed in AjaxOptions? Also see my edits.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery 1.7 or greater, you can try using the on function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.thumb', function () {
        $("#full").attr("src", $(this).data('main'));
    });
});
```

**Response to comment 3**

Is the .thumb element you are attaching the click handler to loaded as part of your partial view?

You are right that you don't want to send javascript in the partial view. If the javascript code you posted is located at the bottom of the layout, I would first try replacing .ready with an anonymous self-executing function. This may not solve your problem, but it is more concise, and the code will still run after the elements are initially loaded:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.thumb', function() { // rest is same });
});
```

One thing you can try is changing on to live, like so:

```
$(function() {
    $('.thumb').live('click', function() { // rest is same });
});
```

Though live is not as efficient as on, it essentially does the same thing for elements that are loaded via ajax. If live works for you though, so should on.

If you're still having problems, try doing this without the Ajax helpers: invoke the ajax call using jQuery manually.

Both live and on should apply to elements loaded after the scripts run, when you load your partial view. If they are not, you might want to use jsfiddle to create a repro and update your question. Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using 1.6. What about this function makes it work?

Comment: It's basically a fix for the problems with the `live` function. I found this article useful: http://www.andismith.com/blog/2011/11/on-and-off/ also, here is the official doc: http://api.jquery.com/on. Can you update to 1.7?